# Identify reasons for laser intensity fluctuation

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, laser, coherence, noise

I got a [Mitsubishi LPC-826](https://laserpointerforums.com/threads/mitsubishi-lpc-826.99171/) laser diode (single mode) with laser driver [iC-HG](https://www.ichaus.de/upload/pdf/HG_datasheet_B3en.pdf). There is no cooling device, but data was captured after 30 mins switching on (which should be temporally stable). The beam was diverged.

A [photodiode](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorProduct.cfm?partNumber=PDA10A) detects following data (DC term is zero-normalized):

[image]

The FFT of the data looks like this, where we do see harmonic frequencies (60 Hz, 120 Hz, 180 Hz, 940 Hz & 2430 Hz):

[image]
[image]

(center part)

**Some facts**

- From the data you see these fluctuations (as dithering noise) are in a cycle of 7~8 ms.
- I can also see these fluctuations when I took images using industrial CMOS cameras, but only when exposure time is < 10 ms.

**My efforts & questions**

I googled around but not convinced this is a quantum shot noise, and I am asking the help of the SE community.

- Where possibly does this noise come from?
- How can I mitigate this noise?

Comment: can you take the Fourier transform of the time series data? From the mention of the 8ms period it sounds like harmonics of 60 Hz mains.

Comment: Were you able to check the laser power source fluctuations?

Comment: @JamesGuana Unfortunately no. But I was told the power source is very stable.

Comment: .that seems to be unscientific, you should get a plot of current & voltage of source overtime unconnected & connected to the laser diodes.

Comment: @JamesGuana So you suggested a power issue of this fluctuation? It is possible I need to check it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not entirely sure in your case, but it is a possible source.

Comment: @AmIAStudent See updated FFTs. You were right one of the harmonics is 60 Hz. Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: If you really believe that the power supply is clean and you are still getting ground noise, then it might be worth looking for ground loops (the bane of any non-trivial, highly sensitive data acquisition system).

Comment: 1) shot noise is white - flat in frequency, which is definitely not what you have. Also if you consider the number of photons in your beam, it would be very small. 2) Are you sure the power supply for your iC-HG is clean? 3) Are you sure the photodiode itself operates normally without noise? Try shining a light bulb at it and get noise power spectral density. It should be pretty flat in the spectrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the power supply. I changed the power supply from

- [image]

to

- [image]

Now the noise is gone:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the update - it's good to see that a better power supply gets rid of the mains ripples.